# If $Var X < \infty $ then both series $\mathbb{E} (X)$ and $ \mathbb{E} (X(X -1))$ are convergent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is this true?

> Let $X$ be a random variable, $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{N}_{0} $.
>    If $\text{Var } X < \infty $ then both series $\mathbb{E} (X)$ and $\mathbb{E} (X(X -1))$ are convergent.

It seems to me that this could be true, but I am having a trouble with proving it. Any hint helps!

Comment: I don’t see any series, or any sequence that can be discussed as being convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of a random variable, we request the expectation $\mu=\mathbb E(X)$ to be convergent. It's not hard to show that
$$\text{Var }(X)=\mathbb E(X^2)-\mu^2.$$
So $\mathbb E(X^2)<\infty$ and hence $\mathbb E(X(X-1))$ is convergent.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{E} (X)$ ?

Comment: Just rearrange the equation from this answer.

Comment: @user560461 As I said, to define the variance, we need $\mathbb E(X)$ to be convergent.